# how to query a record with latest date as part of another linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I am querying using EF linq as below for `Movie` records can have many `Reviews`:

```
var movieSummaries = _db.Movies.AsNoTracking().Select(l => new MovieSummary
            {
                Name = l.Name,                
                Rating = l.Reviews.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date).First().ReviewText
            });
```

However, I don't need the dates to be ordered first, I just need the review with the latest date. Is there a way to do it in a more optimized manner?

Comment: I think your Reviews will already be retrieved in the Order by Date. so in that case you can take `.Last()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try use a linq aux variable, with compare with max date reviews.

Something like this:

```
var moviesSumaries = from m in Movies
let Rating = m.Reviews.FirstOrDefault(d => .Date==m.Reviews.Max(s=>s.Date))?.ReviewText        
          select new {m.Name, Rating};
```

You could use lambda expressions too if you want.

Personaly, I think your propousal of use orderbydescending it's correct. Always depend on the scenary, row amount in table, db index, etc...